# What is the numerical algorithm for polygamma function?

Tags: numerical-methods, gamma-function

would like to write polygamma function as a function in c++, Java or c#

i find this function in Matlab as a psi(x)

Comment: A simple googling gives me: http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/cpp_src/asa103/asa103.html

Comment: Check the NIST ["Digital library of mathematical functions"](http://dlmf.nist.gov) too. But before check if there isn't already a good enough implementation of it around in open source somewhere.

Comment: A simple `R` implementation: `zm <- 20; psi <- function(z){if(z < zm){k <- floor(zm-z)}else{k <- 0};
                    return(log(z+k+1)-1/2/(z+k+1)-1/12/(z+k+1)^2-sum(1/(z+0:k)))};`